# C# Access Remote Registry with Windows 10 not work

Tags: c#, registry, remote-access

I use this code to get the installed .NET Version on a remote machine. With Windows 7 it works perfect but with Windows 10 the following exception throws

> System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.

- The user with i connect, is in the Administrators Group
- The Service "RemoteRegistry" is set to Startup type "Manual"

**Code example**

```
using (RegistryKey remoteHklm = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, hostName))
{
    using (RegistryKey serviceKey = remoteHklm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full", true))
    {
        if (serviceKey != null)
        {
            version = serviceKey.GetValue("Version").ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            version = "error on get version from registry";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have with Windows 10 no write Access to this registry key. Change the second `OpenSubKey` parameter to `false`, you can check in Registry Editor the permission of the key.

```
using (RegistryKey serviceKey = remoteHklm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full", false))
```