# requested registry access is not allowed remotely

Tags: c#, registry, remote-access, registrykey

This is a follow up question to this question:

[C# Access Remote Registry with Windows 10 not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48114242/c-sharp-access-remote-registry-with-windows-10-not-work)

I tried accessing a remote registry key like this:

```
using (RegistryKey regKey = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(remoteMachine))
                        ? RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, enumValues[i]).OpenSubKey(uninstallRegKey)
                        : RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, remoteMachine, enumValues[i]).OpenSubKey(uninstallRegKey, false))
```

I get an error

> requested registry access is not allowed

I added the `false` parameter as the answer in the linked question suggested, but I still get that error.

What else can be done?

Comment: can you connect to remote computer's registry via RegEdit - File -> Connect remote registry ?

Comment: @cerberus I can connect, but when trying to open the registry tree I get access denied

Comment: I CAN open HKEY_USERS, but not HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Comment: @YonatanNir, try connecting to the remote registry hive via RegEdit, and navigate to the subkey that you want to open, right click and check if user group that you belong to has `Read` access, let me know what u see

Comment: @Clint Like I said, I can't even open HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE because of access denied

Answer (score 0):

*Verify* if you have the required access by manually connecting to the remote registry hive via *RegEdit*, and navigating to the subkey that you want to open, right click and verify if that user group that you belong to has *Read* access

In both your *conditional* blocks, explicitly state

```
.OpenSubKey(uninstallRegKey,false);
```

**OR**

```
.OpenSubKey(uninstallRegKey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree, RegistryRights.ReadKey);
```

Comment: I can connect to the remote machine but can't access HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Comment: @YonatanNir, its cllearly a permission issue , you can confirm that without opening, `right click HKLM and check permissions`

Comment: in the security group/usernames check if your name/group exists, ideally you would need to get the admin to add your username. usually there will be a group called `Everyone` in the list, with this group will have `Read` only permissions. which lets you atleast navigate through the HKLM hive

Comment: There are chances that you have just enough permissions to Add group `Everyone` and set it to `Read`. you might want to try that

Comment: @YonatanNir, let me know if what I suggested in the comments above worked

Comment: I got no access for the machine as of now. It may take some time until I can test it again